# Automatically arrange icons on the Mac OS 10.6 desktop in groups

Tags: macos, desktop

Recently I found my estimated 100 desktop symbols re-ordered in 5 bunches: 4 bunches with one in each corner and one bunch in the middle (leaving more space for more crowd between the bunches :). Unfortunately I was not aware how my symbols have been arranged in that way, I cannot find any menu entry nor do I remember the short cut that I might have pressed accidentally. Do you know how to invoke this function? Since I tried out some Apple menu items I found, I now ended up with the desktop arranged by the grid. But I prefer the bunches.

**Update:** Ops, it happened again. I hardly assume this automatic arranging of my desktop happens when I connect an external display in mirror mode having a smaller resolution. Now it looks as follows:

[image: desktop icons arranges in bunches]

Notice the stacking of symbols in the top right that is the result of a formerly "Clean up" command in the desktop's context menu. But anyway, Mac OS created these 5 bunches again. As there is obviously a feature like that implemented, I am curious if I can run it also manually without connecting an external display to make it happen.

Comment: By "symbols" I presume you mean desktop icons?  I have never heard of a built-in way to automatically configure them in "bunches" like you described.  It might be helpful if you could recreate the way they looked on your desktop and post a screenshot here.

Comment: Added a screenshot.

Comment: I think someone like you could really get into BumpTop. Check out this [YouTube vid](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5IswixD5pw). Unfortunately they were bought by Google a little while back so it's difficult to get hold of the application at the moment. :(

Answer (score 1):

Once the desktop fills up, finder will tile and stack icons with a very small offset. I'd guess the algorithm had a bug or your .DS_Store file was corrupt and the system thought it had more icons to pile than it ended up with.

I dont know of a way to intentionally trigger the effect, but it would be nice to have four or five tidy stacks nice and deep rather than using the whole desktop.

Comment: Now I found out how it happens, please see my updated question.

Comment: Wow - I haven't seen the algorithm break like that, but nonetheless - it's not a supported thing to alter the spacing (or it's a really hidden preference that isn't widely known). The picture makes this a much better question.

Comment: @Lars I don't think this is a feature, but rather a glitch that @bmike explained in his answer. Maybe you could try placing only 5 icons on your desktop, connecting the external display, and then see if anything happens. Does it happen every time you connect the display?

Comment: No, it happened only sporadically. Now, that I am using Mac OS Lion, it doesn't happen any more.